# Pattern matching to convert string to Long

Tags: scala, type-conversion, pattern-matching

I have a string that I need to convert into a long if it is not empty or blank. If it either can't be converted(it fails during conversion) or the string is empty or blank I need to run a secondary function. Right now I have a if statement but I would like to convert it to pattern matching if possible to make my code a little cleaner.

Heres what I have right now

```
val stringToConvert = "1234"

if (!stringToConvert.isBlank && !stringToConvert.isEmpty) {
  try {
    val converted = stringToConvert.toLong
    doThingWithConvertedValue(converted)
  }
  catch {
    case _: Throwable =>
      Log.error("Encountered error while trying to convert string to long")
  }
}
else {
  doOtherThing()
}
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you really want to call `doOtherThing()` **only** when `stringToConvert` is blank and not for any other conversion error?

Comment: It's bad practice to catch `Throwable` (in either Scala or Java). You should catch a more specific exception type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the following functions:

```
def doThingWithConvertedValue(l: Long) = println (s"doThingWithConvertedValue($l)")
def doOtherThing() =  println ("doOtherThing()")
```

Your code can be transferred to the following:

```
Try(stringToConvert).filter(stringToConvert => !stringToConvert.isBlank && stringToConvert.nonEmpty).fold(
   sBlankOrEmpty => doOtherThing(),
   nEmpty => Try(doThingWithConvertedValue(nEmpty.toLong)).getOrElse {
     Log.error("Encountered error while trying to convert string to long")
   }
  )
```

Outputs:

```
"1234" => doThingWithConvertedValue(1234)
"notConvertable" => Encountered error while trying to convert string to long
"" => doOtherThing()
```

If you prefer using Pattern matching, you can do it as follows:

```
val stringToConvert = "123s"
stringToConvert match {
  case sBlankOrEmpty if sBlankOrEmpty.isBlank || sBlankOrEmpty.isEmpty => doOtherThing()
  case canBeLong if Try(canBeLong.toLong).isSuccess => doThingWithConvertedValue(canBeLong.toLong)
  case _ => Log.error("Encountered error while trying to convert string to long")
}
```

**Note**:

1. `doThingWithConvertedValue` can throw an exception (which you didnt recover properly for that case in your main file)
2. `.toLong` is used twice `O(n)` Each, but if its fine for you i guess its pretty
   readable

Answer (score 3):

`Try` this:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val stringToConvert = "1234"

Try(stringToConvert.toLong) match {
  case Success(value)                        => doThingWithConvertedValue(value)
  case Failure(_) if stringToConvert.isBlank => doOtherThing()
  case Failure(exception) => 
    Log.error(s"Encounted error while trying to convert string to long: $exception")
}
```

Please note that `isBlank` already covers `isEmpty` case.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```scala
val stringToConvert = "1234"

Option(stringToConvert)
  .map(_.trim)
  .filter(_.isEmpty)
  .fold(ifEmpty =  doOtherThing() { str =>
    trs
      .toLongOption
      .fold(ifEmpty = Log.error("Encounted error while trying to convert string to long"))
           (doThingWithConvertedValue)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest that you don't need a pattern match. Just `fold()` over a `Try`.

```
util.Try(stringToConvert.toLong)
  .fold(exptn => {
    //Log.error() and doOtherThing() go here depending on requirements
    if (stringToConvert.isEmpty) ... //only when empty
    else                         ... //only when non-empty
    ... //do this regardless of empty status
  },doThingWithConvertedValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
val stringToConvert = "1234"

Try(doThingWithConvertedValue(stringToConvert.toLong)).getOrElse {
  println("Encounted error while trying to convert string to long")
  doOtherThing() 
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/TiXXGVdmRzCmXstphLGpeg/7).

Comment: The `doThingWithConvertedValue` call and the `isBlank` check is not covered here.

Comment: Thanks @Ava. I've fixed the  `doThingWithConvertedValue`. Regarding the `isBlank` check, the OP doesn't return anything else in this case. Therefore I hope that when he calls this function he doesn't check the `AnyVal` he gets as a result (since after logging he gets `Unit` which extends `Anyval`) for its type. He can just ignore it. It will make more sense IMO.